# PyPika control order of with clauses

Tags: pypika

I am using PyPika (version 0.37.6) to create queries to be used in BigQuery. I am building up a query that has two `WITH` clauses, and one clause is dependent on the other. Due to the dynamic nature of my application, I do not have control over the order in which those `WITH` clauses are added to the query.

Here is example working code:

```
    a_alias = AliasedQuery("a")
    b_alias = AliasedQuery("b")
    a_subq = Query.select(Term.wrap_constant("1").as_("z")).select(Term.wrap_constant("2").as_("y"))
    b_subq = Query.from_(a_alias).select("z")

    q = Query.with_(a_subq, "a").from_(a_alias).select(a_alias.y)
    q = q.with_(b_subq, "b").from_(b_alias).select(b_alias.z)

    sql = q.get_sql(quote_char=None)
```

That generates a working query:

`WITH a AS (SELECT '1' z,'2' y) ,b AS (SELECT a.z FROM a) SELECT a.y,b.z FROM a,b`

However, if I add the `b` `WITH` clause first, then since `a` is not yet defined, the resulting query:

`WITH b AS (SELECT a.z FROM a), a AS (SELECT '1' z,'2' y) SELECT a.y,b.z FROM a,b`

does not work. Since BigQuery does not support `WITH RECURSIVE`, that is not an option for me.

Is there any way to control the order of the `WITH` clauses? I see the `_with` list in the QueryBuilder (the type of variable `q`), but since that's a private variable, I don't want to rely on that, especially as new versions of PyPika may not operate the same way.

One way I tried to do this is to always insert the first `WITH` clause at the beginning of the `_with` list, like this:
`q._with.insert(0, q._with.pop())`
Although this works, I'd like to use a PyPika supported way to do that.

In a related question, is there a supported way within PyPika to see what has already been added to the select list or other parts of the query? I noticed the `q.selects` member variable, but `selects` is not part of the public documentation. Using `q.selects` did not actually work for me when using our project's Python version (3.6) even though it did work in Python 3.7. The code I was trying to use is:

```
if any(field.name == "date" for field in q.selects if isinstance(field, Field))
```

The error I got was as follows:

```
    def __getitem__(self, item: slice) -> "BetweenCriterion":
         if not isinstance(item, slice): 
    >        raise TypeError("Field' object is not subscriptable")
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to control the order of the WITH clauses after calling `query.with_()` (except for the hack already noted). As a result, I restructured my application to get around this problem. I am now calling `query.with_()` before building up the rest of the query.

This also made my related question moot, because I no longer need to see what I've already added to the query.